# How to use the annotation :no-pattern

Tags: z3

I wrote this [following assertion](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/y5e8):

```
(assert (!
    (forall ((A Set) (B Set))
        (= 
            (= A B) 
            (and (subset A B)(subset B A)))
:no-pattern)))
```

Why does it give the error "`invalid expression, unexpected input`"? To check for syntax errors, I copied the [example](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/URDu) from the [guide](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorialcontent/guide#h28) and replaced the `:pattern (…)` with `:no-pattern`. That [also yields the error](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/dMG5).

Comment: I have deleted a large part of the original question since I don't think I understand patterns just yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The annotation `:no-pattern` expects an expression as argument.
If a universally quantified formula `F` is not annotated with patterns, then Z3 will heuristically select patterns for `F`. The annotation `:no-pattern` instructs Z3 which sub-expressions occurring in `F` should *not* be used as patterns. Here is your example (also available at http://rise4fun.com/Z3/KfO5):

```
(declare-sort Set)
(declare-fun mysubset (Set Set) Bool)

(assert 
    (forall ((A Set) (B Set))
        (! (= 
            (= A B) 
            (and (mysubset A B) (mysubset B A)))
           :no-pattern (mysubset A B))))

(check-sat)
```

*Remark*: Equations (e.g., `(= A B)`) are never selected as patterns by Z3.

Here is a link to the other example http://rise4fun.com/Z3/njVu.

BTW, the annotation `:pattern` accepts two kinds of arguments: an expression; or a *list* of expressions. In the Z3 guide, we have the annotation: `:pattern ((f (g x))`, where `((f (g x))` is a list of length 1 containing the expression `(f (g x))`. If we replace `:pattern` with `:no-pattern`, we get an error because `((f (g x))` is not an expression. On the other hand, `:no-pattern (f (g x)` is a valid `:no-pattern` annotation.

Finally, `:pattern` accepts lists of expressions because Z3 supports multi-patterns ([guide](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/guide)).